# Is it possible for xlam Excel addin to override a sub from a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

The xlam Excel addin I'm building is interacting with externally sourced spreadsheet. The trouble is that the sheet, among other things in Workbook Change event has code that throws a MsgBox popup, messing with automation as it waits for user input. The popup is not called directly - the Workbook Change event is calling a custom Sub called "ShowPopup". Then inside the "ShowPopup" we have MsgBox call.

My thought was that if I could override the ShowPopup sub, I could prevent it from creating the MsgBox. Is it possible to do?

Constraints to the potential solutions:

- Fully overriding the Workbook Change event is a no-go, there is stuff there that's actually needed.
- I can't make any modifications to the code of the externally sourced sheet that the xlam Excel addin is interacting with
- Application.DisplayAlerts = False doesn't work for explicitly called MsgBox'es

Comment: Potentially you could (at runtime) remove the Msgbox call from the other workbook (via the VBA extensibility library) but that might be tricky to manage.  Short of that (or Windows API calls to monitor for and dismiss the Messagebox) I'm not sure there's much you could do.

Comment: @TimWilliams would you be able to point me in the right direction on how to remove that "ShowPopup" Sub using the VBA extensibility library?

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx is a good reference

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I don't want to override MsgBox, I want to override a custom sub called "ShowPopup" that inside has a call to MsgBox. I can't edit the VBA of the file itself, but I have my .xlam addin that is used to assist with interaction with that file. Ideally I want to replace the "ShowPopup" sub that's inside the file with one that's inside the .xlam addin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem, although not in the way I originally planned. In the end it involves overriding the MsgBox Function.

For future reference here are the steps.

1. In any of .xlam addin modules, create a global variable `Global macroRunning As Boolean`
2. In the sub where automation loop sits, we put this before the loop: `macroRunning = True` and opposite after the loop.
3. Create a new module, I called it `MsgBoxHack` and put this code inside:

   ```
   Public Function MsgBox( _
   Prompt, _
   Optional Buttons As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKOnly, _
   Optional Title, _
   Optional HelpFile, _
   Optional Context _
   ) _
   As VbMsgBoxResult

     If IsMissing(Title) Then
         Title = "Overriden MsgBox"
     End If

     If macroRunning = False Then
         MsgBox = VBA.Interaction.MsgBox(Prompt, Buttons, Title, HelpFile, Context)
     End If

   End Function
   ```

   4. That's it, when your global variable `macroRunning` is set to `True` you won't see any MsgBoxes

Downside - This overriden MsgBox function will run on all workbooks you work on while the addin is enabled in Excel.